# Establishing session with web app to crawl

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests, httpsession

I am planning to write a website crawler in Python using Requests and PyQuery.

However, the site I am targeting requires me to be signed into my account. Using Requests, is it possible for me to establish a session with the server (using my credentials for the site), and use this session to crawl sites that I have access to only when logged in?

I hope this question is clear, thank you.

Comment: Sure you can. There are plenty of methods available in `requests` itself to do this, and you can also write your own authentication method if it is not supported. See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/

Comment: Definitely possible, but just be prepared for the site to kick you off and potentially delete your account if they catch you. Depending on the terms of service and the value of the information you are ripping, the site might not be too happy about it. The site likely logs user activity and it is pretty easy to spot a crawler (although it is surprising how few sites are actually looking for this)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

I don't know about PyQuery but I've made crawlers that log in to sites using urllib2.
All you need is to use cookiejar to handle cookies and send the login form using a request.

If you ask something more specific I will try to be more explicit too.

LE:
urllib2 is not a mess. It's the best library for such things in my opinion.

Here's a code snipet that will log in to a site (after that you can just parse the site normally):

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib

"""Adding cookie support"""
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

"""Next we will log in to the site. The actual url will be different and also the data.
You should check the log in form to see what parameters it takes and what values.

"""
data = {'username' : 'foo',
        'password' : 'bar'
       }
data = urllib.urlencode(data)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.siteyouwanttoparse.com/login', data) #this should log us in

"""Now you can parse the site"""
html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.siteyoutwanttoparse.com').read()
print html
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. Ideally, what I'm looking for is a Python Requests snippet to do the relevant cookie/session handling. I want to avoid using urllib2 since it's kind of a mess..